# Is fpclassify(x) == FP_NAN functionally equivalent to isnan(x)?

Tags: c, floating-point, c17

Is `fpclassify(x) == FP_NAN` functionally equivalent to `isnan(x)`?

The same question goes for:

- `fpclassify(x) == FP_INFINITE` vs. `isinf(x)`
- `fpclassify(x) == FP_NORMAL` vs. `isnormal(x)`
- `fpclassify(x) == FP_SUBNORMAL` vs. `issubnormal(x)`
- `fpclassify(x) == FP_ZERO` vs. `iszero(x)`

If they are functionally equivalent, then why need of duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're functionally equivalent. But `fpclassify` allows you to perform a single test and use a `switch` statement, which may be slightly faster and/or produce simpler code than the chained `if`/`else if`/`else` blocks would use to perform type by type checks (assuming `fpclassify` itself has efficient ways to differentiate itself; won't swear to that), e.g. per [the cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fpclassify):

```
const char *show_classification(double x) {
    switch(fpclassify(x)) {
        case FP_INFINITE:  return "Inf";
        case FP_NAN:       return "NaN";
        case FP_NORMAL:    return "normal";
        case FP_SUBNORMAL: return "subnormal";
        case FP_ZERO:      return "zero";
        default:           return "unknown";
    }
}
```

Comment: Conversely, in sitations where just one specific check is needed, it is very likely that this is more efficient than using `fpclassify()`.